# how can i create a text editor for my blog

Tags: web-applications, text-editor

> How to create a text editor for my blog similar to the one used in stackoverflow 'Ask Question'.

Which programming language to use ?
How would it affect the load time of my site ?
And how do i handle the text received ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you'd want to use an existing Javascript widget like TinyMCE: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

Answer (score 0):

I use [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) for general HTML but it isn't designed for entering code. The stackoverflow one is open source though so look in the site source code for the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Markdown (http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).

"Markdown is a text-to-HTML conversion tool for web writers. Markdown allows you to write using an easy-to-read, easy-to-write plain text format, then convert it to structurally valid XHTML (or HTML)."

You'll find a parser for almost any programming language.